# How do I trigger a child job in jenkins, without running the parent job

Tags: jenkins

I have a parent job which runs a child job which keeps failing. How do I trigger the child job, without running the parent again? That is, how do I do it and passing the parent parameters to the child?

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Rebuild Last" option on the left hand side of the child job. Once you click on "Rebuild Last" then it will prompt the parameter fields and corresponding values if you want you can change otherwise click on "Rebuild" option in this way only child jobs can run without using of the parent job always.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did that. In my case, it requests a config file, which includes all the parameters it needs, but it seems not to take it from there...

Comment: How are you defined these parameters in the job? (using build parameterized or ...) & again how are you passing these parameters to child jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[Rebuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin)**.

Note that such "rebuilds" **will only cover parameters that you passed explicitly from parent to child** job.

If your child job relies on implicit references to its upstream (like, evaluating Jenkins-internal data on what parent job triggered the child build) then this will not work as expected. There is no simple solution for that case.